# Will wp_get_attachment_metadata display PDF metadata (eg: keyword, author, description)?

Tags: attachments, pdf

I used [this technique](http://wpengineer.com/1735/easier-better-solutions-to-get-pictures-on-your-posts/) to display attached PDF metadata on a page. It shows the title and path but not info like keyword, author, and description. Can Wordpress access all the properties uploaded with a PDF file and if so, what's the best way to get at them? TIA

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you're gonna need external assistance...

Zend Framework
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4520725

```
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load($pdfPath);

echo $pdf->properties['Title'] . "\n";
echo $pdf->properties['Author'] . "\n";
```

---

XMP PHP Toolkit
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8862702

> XMP Toolkit PHP Extension is a PHP module which includes the Adobe XMP
>   Toolkit SDK. This PHP5 extension will provide classes and methods to
>   manipulate XMP Metadatas from files like jpegs, tiff, png, but also
>   wav, mp3, avi, mpeg4, pdf, ai, eps… It’s based from the Adobe XMP
>   Toolkit SDK 4.4.2. The goal of this extension is to have php classes
>   which can open files, extract metadatas, manipulate them, and put them
>   back within few lines of php code. This project is under GPL v3
>   License.